# Mysql select from inner select with join

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

Can I do something like this ? Bassically I user inner select to select lowest date that is bigger than `NOW()`, for example 9.4.2014 would mathc this, for each event ids. And now I would like to return this, here is the code :

```
SELECT id_event , event_title, event_details, dates.event_date, id_show, id_category,  distance FROM(
SELECT event.id_event id_event, event_title, event_details, min(event_date_time) event_date_time, event_showtime.id_show , event_category.id_category id_category, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.longitude ) - RADIANS(  '18.762441839599678' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM event
JOIN event_showtime ON event.id_event = event_showtime.id_event
JOIN event_category ON event.id_category = event_category.id_category
JOIN (  SELECT id_event, min(event_date_time) as event_date_time FROM event_showtime
WHERE event_date_time > NOW()
GROUP BY id_event ) AS dates ON event.id_event = dates.id_event
 WHERE event_date_time > NOW()
GROUP BY event.id_event
HAVING distance <  '5'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20
  )t
```

Here is the SQLfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/51 with 3 tables :)

How could I access those inner details in the top select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the table aliases to your columns if there are multiple columns that have same names

```
   SELECT 
es.id_show,
e.id_event , 
e.event_title, 
e.event_details, 
d.event_date_time,
ec.id_category, 
 ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( es.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( es.longitude ) - RADIANS(  '18.762441839599678' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( es.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance  
FROM event e
JOIN event_showtime es ON e.id_event = es.id_event
JOIN event_category ec ON e.id_category = ec.id_category
JOIN (  SELECT id_event, 
      min(event_date_time) as event_date_time 
      FROM event_showtime
WHERE event_date_time > NOW()
GROUP BY id_event ) AS d 
  ON (es.id_event = d.id_event AND es.event_date_time =d.event_date_time)
 WHERE d.event_date_time > NOW()
GROUP BY e.id_event
-- HAVING distance <  '5'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Here is the simplified version of your query you are using `HAVING` clause to check the distance should be less than 5 but for second event the distance is `112.773868864733` in my query i have commented the having clause just to show your the results,second thing you asked for the nearest date to `NOW()` but not include past dates so in your provided sample data set for `event_showtime`

```
`id_show`, `id_event`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `event_date_time`
(1, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-03-31 16:13:17'),
(2, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-01 20:00:00'),
(3, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-03-31 15:00:00'),
(4, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-16 11:00:00'),
(5, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-04-23 11:00:00'),
(6, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-30 11:00:00'),
(7, 2, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-29 12:00:00'),
(8, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-24 12:00:00');
```

For event id 1 there are 3 datetimes `2014-03-31 16:13:17 ,2014-04-01 20:00:00,2014-04-24 12:00:00` the date `2014-04-24 12:00:00` is the nearest one for event id 2 the date `2014-04-16 11:00:00` is the nearest one not 23rd one ,third thing you asked in comments that `id_show` is wrong for this your last join from subquery needs another condition with `event_date_time` to be joined to get the exact id you need

Hope it makes sense

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/113)

For your specific requirement to  select nearest dates with distance limitation you can do so

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT 
  es.id_show,
  e.id_event,
  e.event_title,
  e.event_details,
  MIN(es.event_date_time) event_date_time,
  ec.id_category,
  es.distance 
FROM
  event e 
  JOIN event_category ec 
    ON e.id_category = ec.id_category 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      `id_show`,
      `id_event`,
      `latitude`,
      `longitude`,
      event_date_time,
      (
        6371 * ACOS(
          COS(RADIANS('49.20513921227407')) * COS(RADIANS(event_showtime.latitude)) * COS(
            RADIANS(event_showtime.longitude) - RADIANS('18.762441839599678')
          ) + SIN(RADIANS('49.20513921227407')) * SIN(RADIANS(event_showtime.latitude))
        )
      ) AS distance 
    FROM
      event_showtime 
    WHERE `event_date_time` > NOW() 
    HAVING distance < 5) es 
    ON (e.id_event = es.id_event) 
    GROUP BY e.id_event
   ) t
   JOIN `event_showtime` es USING(id_event,event_date_time)
ORDER BY t.distance 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/135)

Comment: Nice but upon trying this up on the fiddle I have provided, and also you have posted, the id_show with datetime does not match, take a look into insert statements please :) but it gives me a new look :) I have fixed it a little http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/106 but still I am missing something :/ with location as it is bad

Comment: The ID event = 2 for that query should be returning date = 23.4 and id_show = 5 :P could you please point me to direction ? where the bug might have been ?

Comment: @XOOLOOO see my updated answer hope it clears all for the nearest date scenario and for id_show

Comment: very much thank you :P but please read again my last coment the second rown of your query should be returning id_show = 5 with date 23 as it is in distance of 5 kilometers. In the query I am looking for location  with latitude of 49.20513921227407 and longitude 18.762441839599678 so it cant return value of 120km in distance. it has to be row with id_show=5 as it is in distance and has lowest date that is > NOW(). Yes you are right `2014-04-16 11:00:00` for the 2nd would work, but I need this to include distance condition, that is much important. More in 2nd comment

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/129 this is the code I have been using up till now, but it is kinda not cool, I just wanted from there results to return for each id_event only one row with datetime that is most relevant to current datetime, by this I thought min and > NOW(), hope you will get me now :)

Comment: so for last example I want that query only to return rows number 3 and 6

Comment: Sir you are a god ! :) I think this work, have to put this under some testing in real db :) thank you much